# Software control system. Which one is it?

Tags: microcontroller, c, software, control-loop

I wrote a software which replaces a discrete closed loop PI control circuit and now I was wondering what kind of control system is this equivalent to? This code drives the PWM which regulates the R_DS,on of a MOSFET to keep currentflow at a certain level.

pseudo-code:

```
while(limit < 10000){
    if( valuefrom_ADC < 1234) {
       dutycycle++;
    }
    else dutycycle--;   
    TIM1->CCR1 = dutycycle;
    limit--;
}
```

Comment: A very slow one. If you calculated the error (valuefrom_ADC - 1234), multiplied this by a gain (K) and then added the result to dutycycle, it would be a simple proportional controller.

Comment: Is it really that slow? I start off with the right initial value for the dutycycle. The variation of the duty cycle is <5% to keep the current at the same level.

Comment: This is still a PI controller. You're just computing the error signal in 1-bit accuracy.

Comment: Plus it will probably oscillate real bad.

Comment: @whatsisname and if I do it like Jon said it won't oscillate?

Comment: @canbus - you just choose a gain so it won't oscillate. BTW there is nothing 'wrong' with your method. It is just unlikely to be an optimal controller, but that doesn't mean it isn't sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is still a PI controller. You've simply truncated the error signal to 1-bit of accuracy.

Here is the inner loop rearranged to make it obvious:

```
...
int error = (valuefrom_ADC < 1234) ? 1 : -1;
dutycycle += error;
TIM1->CCR1 = dutycycle;
...
```

EDIT: I usually call these "Error Integrators" when they have no proportional term.

Comment: It's PI without "P". It is purely integral.

Comment: Yeah lol, the zero "portion" is a bit of a stretch, but the term I-controller feels awkward to me.